# EC2 Amazon: Set up autoscaling tools environment without JRE?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, environment-variables

I am following this guide here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingTheCommandLineTools.html

I don't have JRE, although I have Java 7 setup (I develop in Java). So, I believe that I am stuck on this step in the tutorial: `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jre` (but my `/usr/local` does not have JRE.)

See information here:

```
lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520:~$ ls /usr/local/
bin  etc  games  include  lib  man  sbin  share  src
lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520:~$ which java
/usr/bin/java
lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520:~$ which jre
lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520:~$
```

Should I install JRE separately, or is there a way to configure my system to work with these auto-scaling tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to download JRE.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
Bottom right of that page. Small download should be done within seconds. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `as-cmd` anymore. Please use [AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-welcome.html). Here is the [AWS CLI relevant autoscaling commands](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/index.html)

The reason being, as-cmd is not maintained by Amazon anymore and all the old CLI features have been exported to `AWS CLI`. `AWS CLI` is a one stop shop for all the AWS Services unlike older CLIs where you had to install a separate CLI for individual services.

`as-cmd` is JAva based and hecne your question. However, `AWS-CLI` is python based and in my opinion (which is ofcourse subjective), It is bit faster than older JAva based AWS CLIs.

AWS CLI provides output in JSON format which is much more easier to parse.

BESIDES, You don't have to play with CLI for autoscaling. Now, you can do the same job via [AWS Console](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/12/10/auto-scaling-console/).

Comment: Interesting. Then do you know why Amazon has not updated their tutorial? The link in my OP lists no other option besides running `as-cmd` through JRE.

Comment: @Lucas, that's a good question which Only Amazon can answer. However, Amazon has Full blown documentation for AWS CLI [here](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)